# Unable to add CSS class in Fancybox iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I'm trying to add a class to a div, which is in an iframe, plus the Fancybox iframe. After trying for hours, I can't get it to work. The console log test prints out, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It's Fancybox version 1.3.4.

```
jQuery( ".lightbox" ).fancybox( {
    'width'        : '100%',
    'height'       : '90%',
    'transitionIn' : 'none',
    'transitionOut': 'none',
    'type'         : 'iframe',
    onComplete: function() {
        jQuery('#fancybox-frame' ).contents().find('#right_container').addClass('test123');
        jQuery('#right_container').addClass('test321');
            console.log('test');
        }
```

Here's the page: http://www.rescue3international.com/onlinetraining.php

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, I am getting many errors/warnings.

So in your page, the content is loaded using an iframe, and then when clicked, the fancybox is loaded in another iframe. Can you just `console.log(jQuery('#fancybox-frame'));`? I can't do it here because the iframe url redirects to the parent url.

I think, you can't get the iframe content because the warning shows the security errors displayed by the browser.

```
Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'http://earthexperience.com/r3/faq': 'GOFORIT' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored. 

Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.rescue3international.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://earthexperience.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. console.log(jQuery('#fancybox-frame')) works:

[iframe#fancybox-frame, context: document, selector: "#fancybox-frame", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
0: iframe#fancybox-frame
context: document
length: 1
selector: "#fancybox-frame"
__proto__: Object[0]

The X-Frame-Options is so that the login/logout will work in an iframe.

And the block a frame should be the vimeo player. That's what it tells me in the Chrome console.

Thanks!